# Read the timestamp of the transaction via JSON RPC?

Tags: json-rpc, raw-transaction

How do I retrieve the timestamp of a mined transaction using the JSON RPC?

Comment: Did you try to read out the block which includes the transaction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JSON-RPC#eth_getblockbynumber and the time stamp is returned as part of the result.

The data returned by eth_getBlockByNumber is the same as the data returned by eth_getBlockByHash below:

```
// Request
curl -X POST --data '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"eth_getBlockByHash","params":["0xe670ec64341771606e55d6b4ca35a1a6b75ee3d5145a99d05921026d1527331", true],"id":1}'

// Result
{
  "id":1,
  "jsonrpc":"2.0",
  "result": {
    "number": "0x1b4", // 436
    "hash": "0xe670ec64341771606e55d6b4ca35a1a6b75ee3d5145a99d05921026d1527331",
    ...
    "timestamp": "0x54e34e8e" // 1424182926
    ...
```